# Understand what decomposition of the exponents of the complete cycle permutation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

If we will look at the cycle structure of $S_4$, then we have $6$ different $4$-cycles. They are $$(1234), (1243), (1324), (1342), (1423), (1432).$$
And we have  $3$ disjoint multiplying transpositions. They are $$(12)(34), (13)(24), (14)(23).$$

I can determine them by thinking of partition of $4$.

They have relation as follows:
$$(12)(34)=(1324)^2=(1423)^2$$
$$(13)(24)=(1234)^2=(1432)^2$$
$$(14)(23)=(1243)^2=(1342)^2$$

> - What does this relation tell us?
> - I wonder this: Can we find $n$-cycle permutaton in $S_n$ such that any power of it is a product of all different disjoint transposition? 
>     For example; Does there exist any $10$- cycle $\alpha$ in $S_{10}$ such that $\alpha^k=(1\ 2)\ (3\ 4)\ (5\ 6)\ (7\ 8)\ (9\ 10)$.

---

$\textbf{My attempt:}$ Let $\beta= (1\ 2)\ (3\ 4)\ (5\ 6)\ (7\ 8)\ (9\ 10)$. Then $\beta^2=1$. Assuming there exist any  $\alpha $ for suitable $k$ we have
$(\alpha^k)^2=\beta^2=1\Longrightarrow 2k\mid 10\Longrightarrow k\mid 5.$ Let $k=5$. Then $\alpha^5=\beta$. I could not continue after that.  I guess, we have similar relation as $S_4$.

> - I don't want to find $\alpha$. I want to say about something existence of it.

Comment: Any element in $S_n$ of order 2 can be expressed as a product of disjoint 2-cycles.  Thus if $\alpha$ has even order $n$, then $\alpha^{n/2}$ is a product of disjoint 2 cycles.  So any 10-cycle raised to the 5th power will have your desired form (and you can faff about with the entries to get the fifth power to be any particular product of 5 2-cycles.

Comment: @ Jonathan Brown  Can you give me a link for your first sentence. In $S_3$ how can you find disjoint $2$-cycle such that $(1\ 3)=(?\ ?)(?\ ?)$ . the order of $(1\ 3)$ is $2$.

Comment: (1 3) already counts as being a product of 2-cycles.  In math we are a bit loose with the notion of product.  A thing by itself counts as a product of one item.  We even allow for the empty product, which is always defined to be 1.

Comment: To see what every element of $S_n$ of order 2 can be expressed as a product of disjoint 2-cycles, use that any element of $S_n$ can be expressed as a product of disjoint cycles (of lengths 2 and greater).  Since disjoint cycles commute, if an element, when expressed as such a product, contains any cycles of length greater than 2, the order will be greater than 2.